# Position absolute div in center of screen view

Tags: html, css

I want to place div that has  absolute position in center of the screen view (scrolled or not scrolled).

I have this but its places div in mid od the document and not mid of current view.

```
#main {
    width: 140px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid Black;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-70px;
    margin-top:-50px;   
}
```

Answer (score 110):

Use the following CSS:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: most elegant solution so far .. works on all boxes of all sizes and proportions and no customization needed. Is it cross browser compatible ?

Comment: This has a wierd effect on the size of the element and the content in it. For instance without left:50% the element will take up as much width space as needed but with left:50% it gets a size magically and breaks the content into multiple lines.

Comment: Also recommend adding a `z-index: 20` (or any value greater than 1 should do) to ensure it appears above other content on the screen).

Answer (score 55):

Change `position:absolute` to `position: fixed` and you should be good to go!

When you say position - absolute, the reference div is the parent div that has a position - relative. However if you say position -fixed, the reference is the browser's window. which is wat you want in your case.

In the case of IE6 i guess you have to use CSS Expression

Comment: Except in IE6 and mobile browsers.

Comment: it have to work in all browsers, javascript solution is accepted

Comment: u dont have to worry too much about ie6... it has been considered dead for a long time now

Comment: check the simple and most effective solution from @13209dy below.. Couldn't find a better solution for this so far

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to change your element's position to `fixed`, here is a solution with keeping your element `absolut`.

Since CSS's `calc()` is supported by all browsers now, here a solution using `calc()`.

```
#main {
    width: 140px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid Black;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50vh - (/* height */100px / 2));
    left: calc(50vw - (/* width */140px / 2)); 
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of this and was exactly what I needed for this case - great suggestion @Robert Hahn.

Comment: Perfect for when you still need your element absolute. Awesome answer!

Comment: Can anyone explain how the calculation achieves what OP is asking for. Great solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `margin` and `position: fixed` :

```css
#main{
    width: 140px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    /* Centering #main on the screen */
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

It centers the `div` by increasing the `margin` on all sides to fit the whole screen.

EDIT: I found out there is a shorthand for `top,right,bottom,left` that is `inset`. It has been implemented in major browsers and you can see the compatibility on other browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=inset)

So to absolutely center a div on a screen:

```css
#main{
    width: 140px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    /* Centering #main on the screen */
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    inset: 0;
}
```

Comment: working fine for me. thanks

Answer (score 4):

A bit more complex way is to use multiple outer boxes. This method works well with or without hard coded width/height of the middle box (background colors added just to show what each box does):

```css
/* content of this box will be centered horizontally */
.boxH
{
  background-color: rgba(0, 127, 255, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

/* content of this box will be centered vertically */
.boxV
{
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

/* content of this box will be centered horizontally and vertically */
 .boxM
{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  some text in the background
</div>
<div class="boxH">
  <div class="boxV">
    <div class="boxM">
      this div is in the middle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/7cj1775e/

If you want display div in the middle regardless of the scroll position, then change `position` to `fixed`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to place absolutely positioned text in the center with the following:

```
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
left: 1%;
right: 1%;
```

This is a variation of the answer from Kenneth Bregat.  It maintains `absolute` positioning rather than `fixed`, plus it solves text wrapping issues mentioned in some answers.  Don't forget that the parent will need `relative` positioning.

Answer (score 2):

##### Using absolute.

In CSS:

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

In tailwindcss:

```html
<div class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -mr-[-50%] w-[140px] h-[100px] -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this trick:

```
position: absolute;
height:200px;
top: 0;
left: 1%;
right: 1%;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
margin-left: -half_of_the_div;
left: 50%;
position: fixed;
```

[example on codepen](http://codepen.io/pietervdd/pen/BoDFz)

Comment: The answer you gave is already part of askers question. Check it.